# Tangent of a circle

Tags: geometry

While I was preparing for $AIME$, I ran into a question regarding circles and their tangents(on a coordinate plane). I've read several posts regarding similar question types but I haven't found a systematic way of finding tangent points on a circle given the equation of a circle and a point outside the circle that is intersected by the tangent/s.

For example, 
Find the equation of the tangent/s of circle a with center $(5, 5)$ and a radius $3$, and intercepting the point $(15, 10)$.

Any non-calculus based methods would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Theorem of Thales is useful here.  Look at the circle which has, as diameter, the line segment connecting the center of your circle and the external point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, let the equation of the tangent be $y=mx+c$ then satisfying this equation by the point $(15, 10)$ , we get $$10=m(15)+c$$ $$15m+c=10$$ 
$$c=10-15m\tag 1$$ 
Now, the length of perpendicular from the center $(5, 5) $ to the tangent $y=mx+c$ must be equal to the radius $3$ of the circle, hence we have  $$\frac{|m(5)-5+c|}{\sqrt{m^2+(-1)^2}}=3$$
$$\frac{|5m-5+10-15m|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=3$$
$$|5-10m|=3\sqrt{m^2+1}$$
$$25+100m^2-100m=9m^2+9$$ $$91m^2-100m+16=0$$ 
On solving above quadratic equation for $m$, we get 
$$m=\frac{50\pm 6\sqrt{29}}{91}$$ By substituting these values in the eq(1), we get $$m=\frac{50+6\sqrt{29}}{91}\implies c=10-15\left(\frac{50+6\sqrt{29}}{91}\right) =\frac{160- 90\sqrt{29}}{91}$$

$$m=\frac{50-6\sqrt{29}}{91}\implies c=10-15\left(\frac{50-6\sqrt{29}}{91}\right) =\frac{160+ 90\sqrt{29}}{91}$$

Hence, we get two tangent lines from the external point $(15, 10)$ to the given circle as follows $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{y=\left(\frac{50+6\sqrt{29}}{91}\right)x+\frac{160- 90\sqrt{29}}{91}}}$$ &

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{y=\left(\frac{50-6\sqrt{29}}{91}\right)x+\frac{160+90\sqrt{29}}{91}}}$$

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Find X(p, q), the midpoint of C(5, 5) and P(15, 10).

(2) Find R, the length between X and C.

(3)     Use X as center and R as radius to draw a circle cutting the original at M, and N.

(4) Use two-point form to get the equations of the required tangent.